# sql date parameterized query asp classic

Tags: sql, parameters, asp-classic

I am trying to save a date to a SQL table using a parameterised query in ASP classic.

The field is set to type date and I have tried things like

```
Set sqlParameters(0)=cmdCreateParameterObj.CreateParameter("@DocDate", adDbDate, adParamInput, , "20160928")
```

The error I get is

> Application uses a value of the wrong type for the current operation.

I have tried changing adDbDate to other things but no luck so far.

Any ideas?

Edit - this is the function I call which appends all of my parameters stored in the array:

```
Function executeSQL(sqlQuery, allParameters)
Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = DB 
cmd.CommandText = sqlQuery 
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText 
cmd.NamedParameters = true 
cmd.Prepared = true 
For p=0 To UBOUND(AllParameters) 
cmd.Parameters.Append AllParameters(p) 
Next 
Set TBL=cmd.Execute() 
Set cmd=Nothing 
End Function
```

Comment: Depending on what SQL RDBMS you are using `adDbDate` is likely the wrong parameter type. See [Data Type Mapping](http://www.carlprothman.net/Technology/DataTypeMapping/tabid/97/Default.aspx). More likely should be `adDBTimeStamp` *(135)*, plus I doubt any RDBMS will auto convert `20160928` to a datetime value. plus your syntax is wrong try `cmdCreateParameterObj.Parameters.Append cmdCreateParameterObj.CreateParameter("@DocDate", adDBtimeStamp, adParamInput, 8, "2016-09-28")`.

Comment: Thanks for this - changing to adDbTimeStamp and adding hyphens to the date did the trick.

Comment: I have a function for executing my sql commands with paremeters

Comment: Function executeSQL(sqlQuery, allParameters)

   Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
   Set cmd.ActiveConnection = DB   
   
   cmd.CommandText = sqlQuery
   cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
   
   cmd.NamedParameters = true
   cmd.Prepared = true
   
   For p=0 To UBOUND(AllParameters)
  cmd.Parameters.Append AllParameters(p)
   Next
   
   Set TBL=cmd.Execute()
   Set cmd=Nothing

End Function

Comment: Thought that might be it, would be useful though for others and to give some context to the question if you [added that code into your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39754916/edit) rather then posting it in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for defining a `Parameter` on an `ADODB.Command` is not ideal *(having said that [OP has since confirmed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39754916/sql-date-parameterized-query-asp-classic?noredirect=1#comment66807285_39754916) that they pass the parameters into another function, so this approach is fine)*.

Instead try this;

```vb
Dim cmd

Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
With cmd
    'Set CommandType, ActiveConnection etc.
    '...
    'Adding parameters
    Call .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@DocDate", adDBTimeStamp, adParamInput, 8, "2016-09-28"))
    '...
    'Execute and return results
End With
'...
'After use release memory
Set cmd = Nothing
```

*<sup><sup>`...`</sup> - Denotes other required code to make the `ADODB.Command` object work, as question is quite limited on details, this information is left for the OP to workout (plenty of resources on SO that show how to do this).</sup>*

Also changed the data type named constant to `adDBTimeStamp` *(135)* as most RDBMSs use this over `adDBDate` *(133)*.

---

#### Useful Links

- [A: ADO Command Parameter Not Passing to Stored Procedure or Stored Procedure 'Ignoring' Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35530750/692942) *(details using Named Constants and correctly structuring Parameters)*.
- [Data Type Mapping](http://www.carlprothman.net/Technology/DataTypeMapping/tabid/97/Default.aspx) *(Most useful link I've ever found for ADO named constants and how they map to data types in various RDBMSs)*.
- [A: Using Stored Procedure in Classical ASP .. execute and get results](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20702205/692942) *(Might find this useful for structuring `ADODB.Command` parameterised queries)*.