# Why does my Classic ASP code insert a duplicate record (i.e. two records instead of one)?

Tags: database, insert, asp-classic

It's a simple piece of ASP code. I shouldn't be having problems with it. Yet, here it is!

I have searched through Stack Overflow and can't find an answer. I have an SQL insert that keeps creating two records. I can't find a reason, rhythm nor rhyme to resolve this issue. What is causing me to have this duplicate record?

```
<%
set conn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; DATA 

SOURCE=c:/inetpub/wwwroot/website/database/msg.mdb"
sql="INSERT INTO msg (uid,thisuid,bizid,ucomments,posted) VALUES 
('"&request("uid")&"','"&request("thisuid")& 
"','"&request("bizid")&"','"&request("ucomments")&"','"&Now&"');"

Set rs= Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rs.Open sql, conn, 3, 2
conn.Execute sql
conn.close

'response.redirect "show-msg.asp"
%>
```

Comment: I feel this needs to be asked but why are you using an MSAccess database to power a web application? There is no excuse to be at least using SQL Server Express edition to power smaller websites, MSAccess was never designed to run in a web-based environment. You don't need to Open the `ADODB.Recordset` and call `Execute()` on the `ADODB.Connection` these both execute the `sql` hence the two records.

Comment: Be careful with SQL injection here - this should not go onto the internet until that is fixed.

Comment: @halfer so true. That's how servers get compromised and become part of botnets. But we can't fix the world, I guess. :-(

Comment: Ah, but we can try, @ShadowWizard `:=)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You open your SQL statement with `rs.open` and then you execute it with `conn.execute` -> double insert There's no need to create a recordset for an insert, the `conn.execute` is enough.

However, both methods `rs.Open` and `conn.Execute` are open to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) due to the way the SQL statement has been constructed. In this scenario, the best approach is to sanitise any input before passing directly into a SQL Statement and switch to using [parameterised queries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20702205/692942) which use the `ADODB.Command` object.

Comment: The blatant [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) though is a problem, they should use [the `ADODB.Command` object with a `CommandType` of `adCmdText`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20702205/692942) instead of `ADODB.Connection`'s `Execute()` method.

Comment: Thank you Sir! I knew it was something small. Haven't work with an insert in a while. Thanks again!

Comment: @JamesNelson I strongly recommend you switch to using `ADODB.Command` instead of persisting with the current approach or it will come back to haunt you in the end.

Comment: Haven't done this type of programing in a long time now. Over 12 years now. Ever since the Red Alert worm took out all my servers. During that time my main competitor snached up my domain name and cyber squted on it for 10 years. I finally have it back and have started developing again. A lot has changed since then. Be patient with me, I'm trying! I'll have to look into the ADOODB thing. I have seen references to it but, I don't know anything about it yet. Thanks for your help guys. I'm keeping a list of everyone that has helped along the way.

Comment: @JamesNelson don't worry the question stays around for the benefit of everyone, just want to make sure the right advice is being given for everyone's benefit. Keep at it, to be honest, you might want to look into new tech like ASP.Net using VB.Net if you are comfortable with VBScript the jump isn't too big and Classic ASP / VBScript are over 20+ years old now.